# Docker build fails after macOS Catalina upgrade

Tags: docker, macos-catalina, docker-build

I had a build that worked before upgrading to Catalina MacOS.  Once I upgraded I get this error:
`error from sender: failed to xattr static/._chestefield_club_logo_ver_01-removebg.png: operation not permitted
[image]

My docker file:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN \
  apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip \
  && apk upgrade --update \
  && apk add --update alpine-sdk \
  && apk add libffi-dev openssl-dev \
  && apk --no-cache --update add build-base

COPY . /app

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
  gcc musl-dev

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Cleanup dev dependencies
RUN apk del -f .build-deps

RUN chmod 444 app_pusher.py
RUN chmod 444 requirements.txt

# Service must listen to $PORT environment variable.
# This default value facilitates local development.
#ENV PORT 80
ENV PORT 443

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "python", "app_pusher.py" ]
```

I've given Full Disk Access to the docker app, but the error still persists.
Has anyone else run into a similar issue with docker and Catalina and were able to resolve it?

Comment: I had run "sed" to replace and a lot of weird sedDFIsdoF files were created...

Answer (score 3):

run `dot_clean -n`  in your folder first. then build the docker